# optimization more than one variable one constraint

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

Hi.
My question is how to show that the existens of the minimum value which I found to be **4**.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Cauchy Schwartz inequality, $4(x+y+z)=(x+y+z)(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac4z)\ge (1+1+2)^2$, so $x+y+z\ge 4$ and this minimum is achieved when $x=1,y=1,z=2$.

How did you get $3$??

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you please explain in more details ?

Comment: @Jacksoja Let $u$ be the vector $(\sqrt{x},\sqrt{y},\sqrt{z})$ and $v=(1/\sqrt{x},1/\sqrt{y},4/\sqrt{z})$. Nemo is using Cauchy-Schwartz to show $|u|^2\cdot |v|^2\ge |u\cdot v|^2$, along with the fact that $|v|^2=4$.

Comment: Thanks but the last component of v should be 2 not 4

Comment: How one does in general decide what components does  the vector U and the vector V have ?

Comment: You can choose any components and the inequality remains valid. However those components which allow a solution with equality possible will give you the true minimum.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method of Lagrange multipliers.  Let $g(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{4}{z}$.  Then the extreme points $(x,y,z)$ of $\ell(x,y,z)$ subject to the constraint that $g(x,y,z) = 4$ satisfy $\nabla \ell = \lambda \nabla g$ for some $\lambda$.  Therefore
\begin{align*}
    1 &= -\frac{1}{x^2}\lambda &\implies -\lambda &= x^2\\
    1 &= -\frac{1}{y^2}\lambda &\implies -\lambda &= y^2\\
    1 &= -\frac{4}{z^2}\lambda &\implies -\lambda &= \frac{z^2}{4}\\
\end{align*}
So
$$
    x^2 = y^2 = \frac{z^2}{4}
$$
Since all of $x$, $y$, and $z$ are positive, we can take square roots and get
$$
    x= y = \frac{z}{2}
$$
Now remembering that $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{4}{z} = 4$, we have
$$
    \frac{2}{z} + \frac{2}{z} + \frac{4}{z} = 4 \implies z=2
$$
Therefore $x=y=1$ and $z=2$.  The critical value is $1+1+2=4$.

It's a little bit trickier to show definitively that this is a global minimum.  There are second-order conditions, or you can use pictures, or you can evaluate at nearby points to show that they have larger values.

Comment: Thanks alot ! but how to prove that this the global minimum ?

Comment: There are hessian matrices which might help, but they are an overkill for this problem. Best thing is to notice that there is only one set of positive no.s which extremizes the function and check in the neighbourhood as Matthew Leingang said.